# Interactive Brokers: Automating collection of client account position without TWS/IB Gateway

Tags: interactive-brokers

I'm trying to create a dashboard where I can show my clients their account positions, updated on a daily basis. I know IB offers the TWS/IB Gateway solution however I'm looking for a more lightweight way to automate the collection of account position data on a daily basis. My issue with TWS/IB Gateway is that they need to be installed and run with a GUI, which makes it difficult to do so using a headless server (e.g. using AWS).

I've considered parsing account statements using [ib-flex-analyzer](http://github.com/wesm/ib-flex-analyzer) (I believe they are HTML) however I'm not sure how I would automatically download all individual the account statements in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

IB has something called "Flex Web Service", which allows you to download flex queries without being logged in; see [Using the Flex Web Service](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/am/am/reports/flex_web_service_version_3.htm).
The R package [`IButils`](https://github.com/enricoschumann/IButils), which I maintain, has a function `flex_web_service`, which allows you to download queries. In R, you could write:

```
library("IButils")
flex_web_service(file = "~/my_files/my_report.csv",
                 token = "12345678901234567890",
                 query = 123)
```

This would download your flex query `123` and store it under the specifed `file` name.

Comment: Interesting. What is the "token"?

Comment: You get it from IB: before you can use the service, you need to activate it in account management; then you receive the token.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't heard of Flex Web Service but I'll look into this! So if I understand correctly, I define the query on IB's website and then I run the query like you did here, like a bonafide Web API?

Comment: Yes; in account management, define a flex query, to which IB will assign some number (argument `query` in the above function). Also in account management, activate Flex Web Service and note the `token`. With query number and token you can now download the flex query without being logged in.